# Getting error 0xC00CEF03 when I try to add a tracing rule in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I've installed the IIS failed request tracing rules feature on my server (Windows Server 2016), and I'm trying to add a new rule.  When I click "Finish" to add the new rule, this error pops up:

[image: error img]

I can't seem to find anything on Google as to why this error would occur in this circumstance, and I've tried changing the Providers to no avail.  I'm trying to trace HTTP 500 internal server errors.  How can I fix this?

This error is also popping up when I try to perform various other configuration changes in the IIS manager so it seems to be something fundamental.

Comment: What are the IIS role services you enabled?

Comment: I don't understand quite what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

0xC00CEF03 error code translates to WR_E_NSPREFIXWITHEMPTYNSURI which refers to “Writer: cannot use prefix with empty namespace URI” ([Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753129(v=vs.85))).

This error occurs when there is something wrong with the web.config file. It’s probably corrupted or there are incompatible tags and parameters. As a result of this corruption and incompatibility, IIS is not able to read this file. Therefore, it can’t make a change.

The issue mostly happens after migration because a piece of configuration that works in the older version of IIS (and .NET Framework) probably became unsupported in the newer version.

The shortest way of finding what part of the web.config is causing the issue is to remove sections one by one and test. High-level steps:

1. Remove a section from the bottom of the file (Let’s say you removed `system.serviceModel` section)
2. If the issue goes away, add the section back and start removing the subsections of it one by one. (For example, `ws2007HttpBinding` subsection in `system.serviceModel` section)
3. If the issue goes away again, bring the subsection back and go through each lines. Prefixes like `wsid:`, `asm:`, and `trust:` are the most common causes of this issue

Source: [0xC00CEF03 error (Cannot use prefix with empty namespace URI)](https://port135.com/0xc00cef03-empty-namespace-uri/)